# Xamarin Forms - iOS Use webView in app, and not in default browser

Tags: android, ios, webview, uiwebview, xamarin.forms

I'm been using the WebView in my project to show a couple of webpages in app.
On Android this works fine. but on iOS it's open the default browser insted of showing it in app, like when you use

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(e.Url))
```

My code look like this

```
    webView = new WebView
    {
        Source = new UrlWebViewSource
        {
            Url = "http://www.google.com",
        },
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
    };

    this.Content = webView ;
```

Any one here who know how to make the iOS open the page in-app ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Device.OpenUri` will often even according to the `Xamarin` documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri/p/System.Uri/), navigate outside the application.

If you want to host the content within your application, the best approach would be to embed the `Webview`, that it looks like your doing, and set the `.Source` to a url.

I don't understand why your using `Device.OpenUri` if you have a `WebView` instance already on your page.

Just set the `.Source` property of the `WebView` to point at some url.

For example:-

```
WebView objMyWebView = new WebView();

objMyWebView.Source = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: The device.openUri was just to explain what i didn't want it to do, but what it look like it was doing.

anyway found my problem.
the problem was that i attached some events handlers to the webviews events, an on iOS, that disturb the life cycle,